# How to push data in an array of array, if an array have some data already react native?

Tags: arrays, react-native, push, state

I am new to react native. I am facing an issue with pushing data into an array. I have an array location, in this array I have a sub-array called Scoresheets. In scoresheet array I have some data. When I tried to push data in scoresheets array on particular index it always pushes data into every locations scoresheet.

I tried to push data into array :

```
this.state.locations[1].scoreSheets[0].categories.push({
   subscore:0
});

locations: Array(34)
0: {location_id: "23", name: "Salad bar", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
1: {location_id: "24", name: "Grill Station ", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
2: {location_id: "25", name: "Entrée station", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
3: {location_id: "26", name: "Action station", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
4: {location_id: "27", name: "Sushi Station", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
5: {location_id: "28", name: "Soup station ", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
6: {location_id: "29", name: "Specialty station ", scoreSheets: Array(2), foodInspections: Array(0), refrigerations: Array(0)}
```

Whenever tried to push expected result is data push on 1st index of locations array and then push to 0th index of scoresheet array but it push data to every locations.

Answer (score 0):

Your scoreSheets object may be reffing to the same categories object. Every scoreSheets object needs to be a distinct object. Assign a new a new Array of categories to each scoreSheets object. Example:

```
var newScoreSheets = [...categories]
```

Assign the new categories array instead of referring to the same object